# Python index min value list of list

Tags: python, list, min, nonetype, type-2-dimension

I have a 2D list of lists in Python and I need to find the lowest float in column 1, and then return the value in the same row, but at column 0.

```
mylist =  [['someid-1', None] ,['someid-2', 4545.474] ,['someid-3', 200.1515] ,['someid-4', None] ,['someid-4', 0]]
```

In this case I want returned: someid-3

At the moment I am appending **only** values which are **not** `None` and then do this: (which seems complicated for such a "simple" task)

```
    mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    if len(temp_op_distance_list) != 0 and temp_op_distance_list[0][1] != None:
        return temp_op_distance_list[0][0]
```

Some info on the overall Python project.

*The list is about 8000 entries with values 'None' and some `floats`.
This code collects distance to a Mousepointer in 3D space and test all 3D objects in the Programm. When there is the value `None` the object was not hit.*

**Edited**: Proper list formatting - Of course you all are right, pointing out that my list is not correct. Sorry about that.

Comment: How is `200.1515` lower than `0`? And besides, that's not a legal Python list, (`[someid-1][None]` is not a list with two elements) such that it's unclear what you mean or what structure your list actually is. Can you show an example of a list that can evaluate in Python, something like `[[1, 5], [3, 12], [5, -3]]`? And is that the kind of list you mean?

Comment: Your lists are not formatted correctly, you probably meant `[someid_1, None],`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your list is a proper Python List

```
mylist =  [['someid-1', None] ,['someid-2', 4545.474] ,['someid-3', 200.1515] ,['someid-4', None] ,['someid-4', 0]]
```

You can simply create a generator expression, selecting only the Valid Non Zero Items and determine the `min` using the key as `itemgetter(1)`

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> min((e for e in mylist if e[1]), key = itemgetter(1))[0]
'someid-3'
```

Comment: My head is not operating at proper efficiency levels. Of course `min()` makes more sense..

Comment: thanks to all of you for the answers already, I will test the code tomorrow.

Comment: May I ask an additional question?

What to do if the list cotains only:
`mylist =  [['someid-1', None] ,['someid-2', None]]`
min throws me an error that the `min() arg is an empty sequence`

kind regards

Comment: found a solution here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036763/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-access-nested-dicts-without-nonetype-errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036763/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-access-nested-dicts-without-nonetype-errors) of course changing tne `KeyError to ValueError` - regards mogh

Answer (score 0):

Combine [filtering](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) with [`min()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min):

```
from operator import itemgetter

id = min(filter(itemgetter(1), mylist), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

- The `filter(itemgetter(1), mylist)` removes all elements whose second element is falsey; `False` in a boolean context. That includes `0` and `None`.
- `min(..., key=itemgetter(1))` finds the lowest value based on the key you give it; so the list with the lowest float value after filtering.
- `[0]` selects the id entry from your list.

A quick demo (with a syntactically correct input list):

```
>>> mylist = [
...     ['someid-1', None], 
...     ['someid-2', 4545.474], 
...     ['someid-3', 200.1515], 
...     ['someid-4', None], 
...     ['someid-5', 0]
... ]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> min(filter(itemgetter(1), mylist), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
'someid3'
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out to import `from operator import itemgetter`