# What is the pythonic way to access nested dicts without NoneType errors

Tags: python, dictionary, styles, nonetype, keyerror

I have a deep nested dict (decoded from json, from the instagram api).
My initial code was like this:

```
caption = post['caption']['text']
```

But that would throw a NoneType or KeyError error if the 'caption' key or the 'text' key doesn't exist.

So I came up with this:

```
caption = post.get('caption', {}).get("text")
```

Which works, but I'm not sure about the style of it. For instance, if I apply this technique to one of the deeper nested attributes I'm trying to retrieve, it looks pretty ugly:

```
image_url = post.get('images',{}).get('standard_resolution',{}).get('url')
```

Is there a better, more pythonic, way to write this? My goal is to retrieve the data, if it's there, but not to hold up execution if it's not there.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just catch the exception?

Comment: I can. I guess because I'm pulling ~7 keys, I didn't want to have to try/except 7 times.

Comment: related: [Python: Change values in dict of nested dicts using items in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918852/python-change-values-in-dict-of-nested-dicts-using-items-in-a-list)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most Pythonic way would be simply to catch the `KeyError`:

```
try:
    caption = post['caption']['text']
except KeyError:
    caption = None
```

This is simple, obvious, and immediately understandable to a Python programmer.

Comment: Please don't put the bodies of `try:` and `except:` on the same line as their respective introductions. It's one of [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)'s Definitely Nots, and unpythonic in its own right.

Comment: Fixed, with apologies to PEP 8.

Comment: Is there a way to generalize this for multiple keys? e.g. if I want to retrieve `caption.text` but also `images.standard_resolution.url` and `user.username` and a few others, do I have to do n try/except blocks?

Comment: You could define a function to retrieve a list of keys with the try/except in there.

Answer (score 14):

Python 3.4 and newer versions contains a contextlib context manager `suppress`, which is for exactly this kind of thing. Suppressing specific errors when you know in advance they may happen and your code can handle it.

```
from contextlib import suppress

sample = {'foo': 'bar'}

with suppress(KeyError):
    print(sample['baz'])
```

Will prevent the `KeyError` from being raised.

So for accessing getting a deeply nested dictionary value, you can use `suppress` like this.

```
value = None
with suppress(KeyError):
    value = data['deeply']['nested']['dictionary']['key']
```

Comment: Most clean and Pythonic solution for fetching multiple lines of nested keys at once using a single `with suppress(KeyError):`

Answer (score 2):

How do you feel about something like this

```
if 'caption' in post:
    caption = post['caption']['text']
```

But it also starts to break down

```
if 'images' in post and 'standard_resolution' in post['images']:
    image_url = post['images']['standard_resolution']['url']
```

So I think the most Pythonic way is to just [ask for forgiveness and not permission](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)

```
try:
    image_url = post['images']['standard_resolution']['url']
except KeyError:
    image_url = None
```

Comment: Don't use bare except, though, or funny bad things will happen. (E.g. `KeyboardInterrupt` getting swallowed)

Answer (score -1):

I'd create a custom dict subclass, and then just address that:

```
class SafeDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self,k):
        if k in self:
            return dict.__getitem__(self,k)
        return None


a = SafeDict({'a':'a'})
print a['a']
>> a
print a['b']
>> None
```

You could either do a custom **init** to handle nested dicts as another instance of SafeDict ( which would allow you to pass them around ) or you could use testing (or a try/except block) to prevent KeyErrors

also, you could just make it an object class, overload `__getattr__` , and then handle things with dot notation.  i tend to prefer that approach ( I first saw this in the Pylons framework )

```
class AttributeSafeObject(object):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        for key in kwargs:
            setattr(self,key,kwargs[key])

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self,name)
        except AttributeError:
            return None

post = AttributeSafeObject({'a':'a'})
print post.a
>> a
print post.title
>> None
```

Comment: The `post` dict is coming from simplejson, I'm not sure how I would get simplejson to return a SafeDict, or to convert a standard dict to a SafeDict.

Comment: Your code for `__getitem__()` would be simpler as `return self.get(k)` (you are mostly rewriting the `get()` method). Anyway, this does answer the question, because even `a = SafeDict({'a': SafeDict({'b': 'b'})})` fails on `a['c']['d']`, which is the problem the question asks to solve.

Comment: If you step back for a second... you'll notice that calling AnyClass(yourdict) really calls `AnyClass.__init__` with the dict as kwargs.   If you inherit a class from `dict`, these kwargs become the dict.  if you inherit from object, you can have fun with __init__.  personally, i would probably go with the object notation.  it makes api programming much easier.

Comment: @EOL nice catch.  i noted in the response that I explicitly didn't include recursion.  This is just an idea to potentially pursue.