# Safe method to get value of nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, methods, except

I have a nested dictionary. Is there only one way to get values out safely?

```
try:
    example_dict['key1']['key2']
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Or maybe python has a method like `get()` for nested dictionary ?

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys

Comment: The code in your question is, in my view, already the best way to get nested values out of the dictionary. You can always specify a default value in the `except keyerror:` clause.

Comment: Note that this won't handle the special case `example_dict = {'key1': None}` (would result in `TypeError`, or, in case `get('key1', {})` was used, `AttributeError`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77230846) for more.

Answer (score 563, accepted):

You could use `get` twice:

```
example_dict.get('key1', {}).get('key2')
```

This will return `None` if either `key1` or `key2` does not exist.

Note that this could still raise an `AttributeError` if `example_dict['key1']` exists but is not a dict (or a dict-like object with a `get` method). The `try..except` code you posted would raise a `TypeError` instead if `example_dict['key1']` is unsubscriptable.

Another difference is that the `try...except` short-circuits immediately after the first missing key. The chain of `get` calls does not.

---

If you wish to preserve the syntax, `example_dict['key1']['key2']` but do not want it to ever raise KeyErrors, then you could use the [Hasher recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405143/190597):

```
class Hasher(dict):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405143/190597
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value

example_dict = Hasher()
print(example_dict['key1'])
# {}
print(example_dict['key1']['key2'])
# {}
print(type(example_dict['key1']['key2']))
# <class '__main__.Hasher'>
```

Note that this returns an empty Hasher when a key is missing.

Since `Hasher` is a subclass of `dict` you can use a Hasher in much the same way you could use a `dict`. All the same methods and syntax is available, Hashers just treat missing keys differently.

You can convert a regular `dict` into a `Hasher` like this:

```
hasher = Hasher(example_dict)
```

and convert a `Hasher` to a regular `dict` just as easily:

```
regular_dict = dict(hasher)
```

---

Another alternative is to hide the ugliness in a helper function:

```
def safeget(dct, *keys):
    for key in keys:
        try:
            dct = dct[key]
        except KeyError:
            return None
    return dct
```

So the rest of your code can stay relatively readable:

```
safeget(example_dict, 'key1', 'key2')
```

Comment: so, python does not have beautiful solution for this case ?:(

Comment: I ran into a problem with a similar implementation. If you have d = {key1: None}, the first get will return None and then you'll have an exception ): I'm trying to figure it out a solution for this

Comment: The `safeget` method is in a lot of ways not very safe since it overwrites the original dictionary, meaning you can't safely do things like `safeget(dct, 'a', 'b') or safeget(dct, 'a')`.

Comment: `safeget` never overwrites the original dictionary. It will either return the original dictionary, a value from the original dictionary, or `None`.

Comment: @unutbu could you explain why overwriting the `dct` value in the for loop does not cause the `dct` argument (which is a mutable dictionary) to be overwritten? It works but I can't understand why.

Comment: @KurtBourbaki: `dct = dct[key]` *reassigns* a new value to the *local variable* `dct`. 
This doesn't mutate the original dict (so the original dict is unaffected by `safeget`.)
If, on the other hand, `dct[key] = ...` had been used, then the original dict would have been modified. In other words, in Python [names are bound to values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). Assignment of a new value to a name does not affect the old value (unless there are no more references to the old value, in which case (in CPython) it will get garbage collected.)

Comment: What about taking a copy of the dict in the beginning of method safeget? (using copy.deepcopy)

Comment: So far good unless `{ 'key1': [ { 'key2' : 'catchme' }, ] }` you try these out

Comment: The `safeget` method will also fail in case the key of a nested dict exists, but the value is null. It will throw `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` in the next iteration

Comment: I like the safeget method! In the spirit that a method should only return one data type how about returning an empty dictionary (`{}`) instead of None?

Comment: Starting with Python 3.4 you may use `with suppress(KeyError):`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45874251/1189659

Answer (score 91):

By combining all of these answer here and small changes that I made, I think this function would be useful. its safe, quick, easily maintainable.

```
def deep_get(dictionary, keys, default=None):
    return reduce(lambda d, key: d.get(key, default) if isinstance(d, dict) else default, keys.split("."), dictionary)
```

Example :

```
from functools import reduce
def deep_get(dictionary, keys, default=None):
    return reduce(lambda d, key: d.get(key, default) if isinstance(d, dict) else default, keys.split("."), dictionary)

person = {'person':{'name':{'first':'John'}}}
print(deep_get(person, "person.name.first"))    # John

print(deep_get(person, "person.name.lastname")) # None

print(deep_get(person, "person.name.lastname", default="No lastname"))  # No lastname
```

Comment: Perfect for Jinja2 templates

Comment: This is a good solution though there also is a disadvantage: even if the first key is not available, or the value passed as the dictionary argument to the function is not a dictionary, the function will go from first element to the last one. Basically, it does this in all cases.

Comment: `deep_get({'a': 1}, "a.b")` gives `None` but I would expect an exception like `KeyError` or something else.

Comment: @edityouprofile. then you just need to do small modify to change return value from `None` to `Raise KeyError`

Comment: Just FYI, doesn't handle nested lists.  I.e. this won't work `deep_get(person, 'lastNames.0.name')`

Answer (score 82):

You could also use python [reduce](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
def deep_get(dictionary, *keys):
    return reduce(lambda d, key: d.get(key) if d else None, keys, dictionary)
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention that functools is [no longer a builtin in Python3](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) and needs to be imported from functools, which makes this approach slightly less elegant.

Comment: Slight correction to this comment: _reduce_ is no longer a built-in in Py3. But I don't see why this makes this any less elegant. It _does_ make it less suitable for a one-liner, but being a one-liner does not automatically qualify or disqualify something as being "elegant".

Comment: Note that using try/except is usually better since it does not involve additional computational burden for checking the validity of the key. So if most of the time the keys exist, then I would recommend try/except paradigm for efficiency.

Answer (score 30):

You can .get an empty dictionary, in the first stage.

```
example_dict.get('key1',{}).get('key2')
```

Answer (score 18):

Building up on Yoav's answer, an even safer approach:

```
def deep_get(dictionary, *keys):
    return reduce(lambda d, key: d.get(key, None) if isinstance(d, dict) else None, keys, dictionary)
```

Answer (score 17):

A recursive solution. It's not the most efficient but I find it a bit more readable than the other examples and it doesn't rely on functools.

```
def deep_get(d, keys):
    if not keys or d is None:
        return d
    return deep_get(d.get(keys[0]), keys[1:])
```

Example

```
d = {'meta': {'status': 'OK', 'status_code': 200}}
deep_get(d, ['meta', 'status_code'])     # => 200
deep_get(d, ['garbage', 'status_code'])  # => None
```

---

A more polished version

```
def deep_get(d, keys, default=None):
    """
    Example:
        d = {'meta': {'status': 'OK', 'status_code': 200}}
        deep_get(d, ['meta', 'status_code'])          # => 200
        deep_get(d, ['garbage', 'status_code'])       # => None
        deep_get(d, ['meta', 'garbage'], default='-') # => '-'
    """
    assert type(keys) is list
    if d is None:
        return default
    if not keys:
        return d
    return deep_get(d.get(keys[0]), keys[1:], default)
```

Answer (score 16):

I suggest you to try `python-benedict`.

It is a `dict` subclass that provides keypath support and much more.

Installation: `pip install python-benedict`

```
from benedict import benedict

example_dict = benedict(example_dict, keypath_separator='.')
```

now you can access nested values using **keypath**:

```py
val = example_dict['key1.key2']

# using 'get' method to avoid a possible KeyError:
val = example_dict.get('key1.key2')
```

or access nested values using **keys list**:

```py
val = example_dict['key1', 'key2']

# using get to avoid a possible KeyError:
val = example_dict.get(['key1', 'key2'])
```

---

It is well tested and open-source on GitHub:

https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict

Note: I am the author of this project

Comment: @perfecto25 thank you! I will release new features soon, stay tuned 

Comment: @perfecto25 I added support to list indexes, eg. `d.get('a.b[0].c[-1]')`

Comment: The from_toml function doesn't seem to be implemented.  And it can be difficult to import BeneDict.

Comment: @DLyons you are wrong, in any case feel free to open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Yes, it's there all right.  Pity I missed it - would have save me some time.  Benedict seems to have some very useful functionality.

Comment: @DLyons thank you, if you have any idea for new features just let me know on GitHub.

Comment: Benedict seemed to install OK with poetry.  But any variants of "from benedict import benedict" gave me cannot import BeneDict error.  I tried a few things like deleting everything from __init__.py but in the end it seemed quicker to load and parse my small, regular toml file otherwise.

Comment: Just open an issue here: https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict/issues

Answer (score 10):

While the reduce approach is neat and short, I think a simple loop is easier to grok. I've also included a default parameter.

```
def deep_get(_dict, keys, default=None):
    for key in keys:
        if isinstance(_dict, dict):
            _dict = _dict.get(key, default)
        else:
            return default
    return _dict
```

As an exercise to understand how the reduce one-liner worked, I did the following. But ultimately the loop approach seems more intuitive to me.

```
def deep_get(_dict, keys, default=None):

    def _reducer(d, key):
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            return d.get(key, default)
        return default

    return reduce(_reducer, keys, _dict)
```

Usage

```
nested = {'a': {'b': {'c': 42}}}

print deep_get(nested, ['a', 'b'])
print deep_get(nested, ['a', 'b', 'z', 'z'], default='missing')
```

Comment: I like the loop because it is way more flexible. For example, it is possible to use it to apply some lambda on the nested field, rather than getting it.

Answer (score 10):

[`glom`](https://glom.readthedocs.io/) is a nice library that can into dotted queries too:

```
In [1]: from glom import glom

In [2]: data = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}}

In [3]: glom(data, "a.b.c")
Out[3]: 'd'
```

A query failure has a nice stack trace, indicating the exact failure spot:

```
In [4]: glom(data, "a.b.foo")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PathAccessError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-2a3467493ac4> in <module>
----> 1 glom(data, "a.b.foo")

~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/neural-knapsack-dE7ihQtM-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/glom/core.py in glom(target, spec, **kwargs)
   2179 
   2180     if err:
-> 2181         raise err
   2182     return ret
   2183 

PathAccessError: error raised while processing, details below.
 Target-spec trace (most recent last):
 - Target: {'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}}
 - Spec: 'a.b.foo'
glom.core.PathAccessError: could not access 'foo', part 2 of Path('a', 'b', 'foo'), got error: KeyError('foo')
```

Safeguard with `default`:

```
In [5]: glom(data, "a.b.foo", default="spam")
Out[5]: 'spam'
```

The beauty of `glom` is in the versatile spec parameter. For example, one can easily extract all first names from the following `data`:

```
In [8]: data = {
   ...:     "people": [
   ...:         {"first_name": "Alice", "last_name": "Adams"},
   ...:         {"first_name": "Bob", "last_name": "Barker"}
   ...:     ]
   ...: }

In [9]: glom(data, ("people", ["first_name"]))
Out[9]: ['Alice', 'Bob']
```

Read the [`glom` docs](https://glom.readthedocs.io) for more examples.

Comment: This is fantastic, exactly what I needed for dynamic XML parsing.

Answer (score 9):

You can use pydash:

```
import pydash as _  #NOTE require `pip install pydash`

_.get(example_dict, 'key1.key2', default='Default')
```

https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: This must be the accepted answer in my view!

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Python 3.4 you may use `with suppress (KeyError)` to access nested json objects without worrying of Keyerror

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(KeyError):
    a1 = json_obj['key1']['key2']['key3']
    a2 = json_obj['key4']['key5']['key6']
    a3 = json_obj['key7']['key8']['key9']
```

Courtesy of Techdragon. Have a look at his answer for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45874251/1189659

Comment: Note that if `key1` is missing, `a1` variable will not be set at all, leading to `NameError` when you attempt to use it

Answer (score 5):

## One-liner solutions

### A popular (but potentially risky) solution

The accepted answer, as well as many others, suggest using [get()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/get.html) with a second parameter an empty `dict`, like this:

```
example_dict.get('key1', {}).get('key2')
```

That will work fine in the case where `example_dict` doesn't have a key named `key1`. However, in this case:

```
example_dict = {'key1': None}
```

we would get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The reason for that is the expression `example_dict.get('key1', {})` would return `None`, because `key1` *does* exist (and so the `get()` method would *not* return the default value that we passed).

### An alternative with `or` (probably safer)

To address the problem described above, a potentially safer alternative would be to do this:

```
(example_dict.get('key1') or {}).get('key2')
```

If `key1` doesn't exist, the expression `(example_dict.get('key1') or {})` would still evaluate to an empty `dict`. But the same would happen when `key1` *does* exist and is `None`.

Here we are using the fact that in Python the expression `a or b` would evaluate to `b` whenever `a` is a *falsy* value (`None` is one of those). That means that the above trick would work not only when `key1` is `None`, but also when it's equal to `False`, `[]`, `0`, `''`, etc. Perhaps those special cases won't be expected at all, but in my practice `None` is a lot more likely to be a valid case that should be considered.

## Comparison

Here is a comparison of three one-liner expressions:

1. `example_dict['key1']['key2']`
2. `example_dict.get('key1', {}).get('key2')`
3. `(example_dict.get('key1') or {}).get('key2')`

| Value of `example_dict` | Expression 1 | Expression 2 | Expression 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `{}` | ❌ `KeyError: 'key1'` | ✔️ OK (`None`) | ✔️ OK (`None`) |
| `{'key1': {}}` | ❌ `KeyError: 'key2'` | ✔️ OK (`None`) | ✔️ OK (`None`) |
| `{'key1': {'key2': 123}}` | ✔️ OK (`123`) | ✔️ OK (`123`) | ✔️ OK (`123`) |
| `{'key1': None}` | ❌ `TypeError`<sup>1</sup> | ❌ `AttributeError`<sup>2</sup> | ✔️ OK (`None`) |

<sup>1</sup> `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`;
<sup>2</sup> `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`.

## A word of caution

All those one-liner solutions can be convenient for occasional usage. But if one finds such functionality is needed often or a stricter validation is desired, I'd recommend using a special function.

Answer (score 4):

for a second level key retrieving, you can do this:

```
key2_value = (example_dict.get('key1') or {}).get('key2')
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple class that can wrap a dict, and retrieve based on a key:

```
class FindKey(dict):
    def get(self, path, default=None):
        keys = path.split(".")
        val = None

        for key in keys:
            if val:
                if isinstance(val, list):
                    val = [v.get(key, default) if v else None for v in val]
                else:
                    val = val.get(key, default)
            else:
                val = dict.get(self, key, default)

            if not val:
                break

        return val
```

For example:

```
person = {'person':{'name':{'first':'John'}}}
FindDict(person).get('person.name.first') # == 'John'
```

If the key doesn't exist, it returns `None` by default. You can override that using a `default=` key in the `FindDict` wrapper -- for example`:

```
FindDict(person, default='').get('person.name.last') # == doesn't exist, so ''
```

Answer (score 3):

I adapted GenesRus and unutbu's answer in this very simple:

```
class new_dict(dict):
    def deep_get(self, *args, default=None):
        _empty_dict = {}
        out = self
        for key in args:
            out = out.get(key, _empty_dict)
        return out if out else default
```

it works with:

```
d = new_dict(some_data)
d.deep_get("key1", "key2", "key3", ..., default=some_value)
```

Answer (score 2):

After seeing [this](http://pingfive.typepad.com/blog/2010/04/deep-getattr-python-function.html) for deeply getting attributes, I made the following to safely get nested `dict` values using dot notation. This works for me because my `dicts` are deserialized MongoDB objects, so I know the key names don't contain `.`s. Also, in my context, I can specify a falsy fallback value (`None`) that I don't have in my data, so I can avoid the try/except pattern when calling the function.

```
from functools import reduce # Python 3
def deepgetitem(obj, item, fallback=None):
    """Steps through an item chain to get the ultimate value.

    If ultimate value or path to value does not exist, does not raise
    an exception and instead returns `fallback`.

    >>> d = {'snl_final': {'about': {'_icsd': {'icsd_id': 1}}}}
    >>> deepgetitem(d, 'snl_final.about._icsd.icsd_id')
    1
    >>> deepgetitem(d, 'snl_final.about._sandbox.sbx_id')
    >>>
    """
    def getitem(obj, name):
        try:
            return obj[name]
        except (KeyError, TypeError):
            return fallback
    return reduce(getitem, item.split('.'), obj)
```

Comment: `fallback` is not actually used in the function.

Comment: Note that this does not work for keys that contain a `.`

Comment: When we call obj[name] why not obj.get(name, fallback) and avoid the try-catch (if you do want the try-catch, then return fallback, not None)

Comment: Thanks @153957. I fixed it. And yes @JW, this works for my use case. You could add a `sep=','` keyword arg to generalize for given (sep, fallback) conditions. And @denvar, if `obj` is say of type `int` after a sequence of the reduce, then obj[name] raises a TypeError, which I catch. If I used obj.get(name) or obj.get(name, fallback) instead, it would raise an AttributeError, so either way I'd need to catch.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do it without using libraries or writing functions
and for a small number quick uses, the simplest way to do it is to
use the `get(..., {})` pattern as many times as needed, for example:

```
example_dict.get('key1', {}).get('key2', {}).get('key3', {}).get('key4', {})
```

Comment: for one-time use it's simple, concise, and fairly readable. If this is a regular use, a function makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

An adaptation of unutbu's answer that I found useful in my own code:

```
example_dict.setdefaut('key1', {}).get('key2')
```

It generates a dictionary entry for key1 if it does not have that key already so that you avoid the KeyError. If you want to end up a nested dictionary that includes that key pairing anyway like I did, this seems like the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another function for the same thing, also returns a boolean to represent whether the key was found or not and handles some unexpected errors.

```
'''
json : json to extract value from if exists
path : details.detail.first_name
            empty path represents root

returns a tuple (boolean, object)
        boolean : True if path exists, otherwise False
        object : the object if path exists otherwise None

'''
def get_json_value_at_path(json, path=None, default=None):

    if not bool(path):
        return True, json
    if type(json) is not dict :
        raise ValueError(f'json={json}, path={path} not supported, json must be a dict')
    if type(path) is not str and type(path) is not list:
        raise ValueError(f'path format {path} not supported, path can be a list of strings like [x,y,z] or a string like x.y.z')

    if type(path) is str:
        path = path.strip('.').split('.')
    key = path[0]
    if key in json.keys():
        return get_json_value_at_path(json[key], path[1:], default)
    else:
        return False, default
```

example usage:

```
my_json = {'details' : {'first_name' : 'holla', 'last_name' : 'holla'}}
print(get_json_value_at_path(my_json, 'details.first_name', ''))
print(get_json_value_at_path(my_json, 'details.phone', ''))
```

> (True, 'holla')
>
> (False, '')

Answer (score 1):

There are already lots of good answers but I have come up with [a function called get](https://github.com/peter/python-heroku-kitchensink/blob/master/util.py) similar to lodash get in JavaScript land that also supports reaching into lists by index:

```
def get(value, keys, default_value = None):
'''
    Useful for reaching into nested JSON like data
    Inspired by JavaScript lodash get and Clojure get-in etc.
'''
  if value is None or keys is None:
      return None
  path = keys.split('.') if isinstance(keys, str) else keys
  result = value
  def valid_index(key):
      return re.match('^([1-9][0-9]*|[0-9])$', key) and int(key) >= 0
  def is_dict_like(v):
      return hasattr(v, '__getitem__') and hasattr(v, '__contains__')
  for key in path:
      if isinstance(result, list) and valid_index(key) and int(key) < len(result):
          result = result[int(key)] if int(key) < len(result) else None
      elif is_dict_like(result) and key in result:
          result = result[key]
      else:
          result = default_value
          break
  return result

def test_get():
  assert get(None, ['foo']) == None
  assert get({'foo': 1}, None) == None
  assert get(None, None) == None
  assert get({'foo': 1}, []) == {'foo': 1}
  assert get({'foo': 1}, ['foo']) == 1
  assert get({'foo': 1}, ['bar']) == None
  assert get({'foo': 1}, ['bar'], 'the default') == 'the default'
  assert get({'foo': {'bar': 'hello'}}, ['foo', 'bar']) == 'hello'
  assert get({'foo': {'bar': 'hello'}}, 'foo.bar') == 'hello'
  assert get({'foo': [{'bar': 'hello'}]}, 'foo.0.bar') == 'hello'
  assert get({'foo': [{'bar': 'hello'}]}, 'foo.1') == None
  assert get({'foo': [{'bar': 'hello'}]}, 'foo.1.bar') == None
  assert get(['foo', 'bar'], '1') == 'bar'
  assert get(['foo', 'bar'], '2') == None
```

Comment: the only one that passes my tests with lists :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on the unutbu's function answer plus:

1. python naming guidelines
2. default value as a parameter
3. not using try but just checking if key is on object

```py
def safe_get(dictionary, *keys, default=None):
    for key in keys:
        if key not in dictionary:
            return default
        dictionary = dictionary[key]
    return dictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```py
def get_nested(dictionary: dict, key: str, default=None, sep: str = '.'):
    if sep in key:
        first_key, other_keys = key.split(sep, 1)
        return get_nested(dictionary.get(first_key, {}), other_keys, default)
    return dictionary.get(key, default)
```

Example of usage:

```py
get_nested(
    {'nest': {'nest2': 777}},
    key='nest.nest2'
)
# returns: 777

get_nested(
    {'abc': {}},
    key='abc.lalala'
)
# returns: None   # 'cause defaut=None

get_nested(
    {},
    key='tyty.nana.qwerty',
    default={}
)
# returns: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since raising an key error if one of keys is missing is a reasonable thing to do, we can even not check for it and get it as single as that:

```
def get_dict(d, kl):
  cur = d[kl[0]]
  return get_dict(cur, kl[1:]) if len(kl) > 1 else cur
```

Answer (score 0):

Little improvement to `reduce` approach to make it work with list. Also using data path as string divided by dots instead of array.

```
def deep_get(dictionary, path):
    keys = path.split('.')
    return reduce(lambda d, key: d[int(key)] if isinstance(d, list) else d.get(key) if d else None, keys, dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've used that is similar to the double get but with the additional ability to avoid a TypeError using if else logic:

```
    value = example_dict['key1']['key2'] if example_dict.get('key1') and example_dict['key1'].get('key2') else default_value
```

However, the more nested the dictionary the more cumbersome this becomes.

Answer (score 0):

For nested dictionary/JSON lookups, you can use dictor

pip install dictor

dict object

```
{
    "characters": {
        "Lonestar": {
            "id": 55923,
            "role": "renegade",
            "items": [
                "space winnebago",
                "leather jacket"
            ]
        },
        "Barfolomew": {
            "id": 55924,
            "role": "mawg",
            "items": [
                "peanut butter jar",
                "waggy tail"
            ]
        },
        "Dark Helmet": {
            "id": 99999,
            "role": "Good is dumb",
            "items": [
                "Shwartz",
                "helmet"
            ]
        },
        "Skroob": {
            "id": 12345,
            "role": "Spaceballs CEO",
            "items": [
                "luggage"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

to get Lonestar's items, simply provide a dot-separated path, ie

```
import json
from dictor import dictor

with open('test.json') as data: 
    data = json.load(data)

print dictor(data, 'characters.Lonestar.items')

>> [u'space winnebago', u'leather jacket']
```

you can provide fallback value in case the key isnt in path

theres tons more options you can do, like ignore letter casing and using other characters besides '.' as a path separator,

https://github.com/perfecto25/dictor

Answer (score 0):

I little changed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43621819/3012785) answer. I added checking if we're using list with numbers.
So now we can use it whichever way. `deep_get(allTemp, [0], {})` or `deep_get(getMinimalTemp, [0, minimalTemperatureKey], 26)` etc

```
def deep_get(_dict, keys, default=None):
    def _reducer(d, key):
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            return d.get(key, default)
        if isinstance(d, list):
            return d[key] if len(d) > 0 else default
        return default
    return reduce(_reducer, keys, _dict)
```

Comment: fails on this: test_dict = {"a":{"b":[{"c":"value"}]}}
        self.assertEqual(safeget(test_dict, ["a", "b", 1, "c"], None)

Answer (score 0):

Recursive method (мб пригодится)

Example dict:

```
foo = [{'feature_name': 'Sample Creator > Contract Details > Elements of the page',
  'scenarios': [{'scenario_name': 'SC, CD, Elements of the page',
                 'scenario_status': 'failed',
                 'scenario_tags': None,
                 'steps': [{'duration': 0,
                            'name': 'I open application Stage and login by '
                                    'SPT_LOGIN and password SPT_PWD',
                            'status': 'untested'},
                           {'duration': 0,
                            'name': 'I open Sample Creator query page',
                            'status': 'untested'},
                           {'duration': 7.78166389465332,
                            'name': 'I open application Stage and login by '
                                    'SPT_LOGIN and password SPT_PWD',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 3.985326051712036,
                            'name': 'I open Sample Creator query page',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 2.9063704013824463,
                            'name': 'Enter value: '
                                    'X-2008-CON-007,X-2011-CON-016 in '
                                    'textarea: project_text_area sleep: 1',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 4.4447715282440186,
                            'name': 'I press on GET DATA',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 1.1209557056427002,
                            'name': 'Verify the top table on Contract Details',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 3.8173601627349854,
                            'name': 'I export contract_details table by offset '
                                    'x:100, y:150',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 1.032956600189209,
                            'name': 'Check data of '
                                    'sc__cd_elements_of_the_page_1 and skip '
                                    'cols None',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 0.04593634605407715,
                            'name': "Verify 'Number of Substances' column "
                                    'values',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 0.10199904441833496,
                            'name': 'Substance Sample Details bottom table '
                                    'columns',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 0.0009999275207519531,
                            'name': 'Verify the Substance Sample Details '
                                    'bottom table',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 3.8558616638183594,
                            'name': 'I export substance_sample_details table '
                                    'by offset x:100, y:150',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 1.0329277515411377,
                            'name': 'Check data of '
                                    'sc__cd_elements_of_the_page_2 and skip '
                                    'cols None',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 0.2879970073699951,
                            'name': 'Click on AG-13369',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 3.800830364227295,
                            'name': 'I export substance_sample_details table '
                                    'by offset x:100, y:150',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 1.0169551372528076,
                            'name': 'Check data of '
                                    'sc__cd_elements_of_the_page_3 and skip '
                                    'cols None',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 1.7484464645385742,
                            'name': 'Select all cells, table: 2',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 3.812828779220581,
                            'name': 'I export substance_sample_details table '
                                    'by offset x:100, y:150',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 1.0029594898223877,
                            'name': 'Check data of '
                                    'sc__cd_elements_of_the_page_2 and skip '
                                    'cols None',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 1.6729373931884766,
                            'name': 'Set window size x:800, y:600',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 30.145705699920654,
                            'name': 'All scrollers are placed on top 6 and far '
                                    'left 8',
                            'status': 'failed'}]}]},
  {'feature_name': 'Sample Creator > Substance Sample History > Elements of the '
                  'page',
  'scenarios': [{'scenario_name': 'SC, SSH, Elements of the page',
                 'scenario_status': 'passed',
                 'scenario_tags': None,
                 'steps': [{'duration': 0,
                            'name': 'I open application Stage and login by '
                                    'SPT_LOGIN and password SPT_PWD',
                            'status': 'untested'},
                           {'duration': 0,
                            'name': 'I open Sample Creator query page',
                            'status': 'untested'},
                           {'duration': 7.305850505828857,
                            'name': 'I open application Stage and login by '
                                    'SPT_LOGIN and password SPT_PWD',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 3.500955104827881,
                            'name': 'I open Sample Creator query page',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 3.0419492721557617,
                            'name': 'Enter value: NOA401800 SYN-NOA '
                                    'A,S4A482070C SYN-ISN-OLD '
                                    'O,S04A482167T,S04A482190Y,CSAA796564,CSCD106701 '
                                    'in textarea: id_text_area sleep: 1',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 49.567158460617065,
                            'name': 'I press on GET DATA',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 0.13904356956481934,
                            'name': 'Open substance_sample_history',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 1.1039845943450928,
                            'name': 'Columns displayed',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 3.881945848464966,
                            'name': 'I export export_parent_table table by '
                                    'offset x:100, y:150',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 1.0334820747375488,
                            'name': 'Check data of '
                                    'sc__ssh_elements_of_the_page_1 and skip '
                                    'cols None',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 0.0319981575012207,
                            'name': "Title is 'Additional Details for Marked "
                                    "Rows'",
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 0.08897256851196289,
                            'name': 'Columns displayed (the same as in top '
                                    'table)',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 25.192569971084595,
                            'name': 'Verify the content of the bottom table',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 4.308935880661011,
                            'name': 'I export '
                                    'additional_details_for_marked_rows table '
                                    'by offset x:100, y:150',
                            'status': 'passed'},
                           {'duration': 1.0089836120605469,
                            'name': 'Check data of '
                                    'sc__ssh_elements_of_the_page_1 and skip '
                                    'cols None',
                            'status': 'passed'}]}]}]
```

Code:

```
def get_keys(_dict: dict, prefix: list):
    prefix += list(_dict.keys())
    return prefix


def _loop_elements(elems:list, prefix=None, limit=None):
    prefix = prefix or []
    limit = limit or 9
    try:
        if len(elems) != 0 and isinstance(elems, list):
            for _ in elems:
                if isinstance(_, dict):
                    get_keys(_, prefix)
                    for item in _.values():
                        _loop_elements(item, prefix, limit)
        return prefix[:limit]
    except TypeError:
        return


>>>goo = _loop_elements(foo,limit=9)
>>>goo
['feature_name', 'scenarios', 'scenario_name', 'scenario_status', 'scenario_tags', 'steps', 'duration', 'name', 'status']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def safeget(_dct, *_keys):
    if not isinstance(_dct, dict): raise TypeError("Is not instance of dict")
    def foo(dct, *keys):
        if len(keys) == 0: return dct
        elif not isinstance(_dct, dict): return None
        else: return foo(dct.get(keys[0], None), *keys[1:])
    return foo(_dct, *_keys)

assert safeget(dict()) == dict()
assert safeget(dict(), "test") == None
assert safeget(dict([["a", 1],["b", 2]]),"a", "d") == None
assert safeget(dict([["a", 1],["b", 2]]),"a") == 1
assert safeget({"a":{"b":{"c": 2}},"d":1}, "a", "b")["c"] == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a package deepextract that does exactly what you want: https://github.com/ya332/deepextract
You can do

```py
from deepextract import deepextract
# Demo: deepextract.extract_key(obj, key)
deeply_nested_dict = {
    "items": {
        "item": {
            "id": {
                "type": {
                    "donut": {
                        "name": {
                            "batters": {
                                "my_target_key": "my_target_value"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
print(deepextract.extract_key(deeply_nested_dict, "my_target_key") == "my_target_value")
```

returns

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

My implementation that descends into sub-dicts, ignores `None` values, but fails with a TypeError if anything else is discovered

```py
def deep_get(d: dict, *keys, default=None):
    """ Safely get a nested value from a dict

    Example:
        config = {'device': None}
        deep_get(config, 'device', 'settings', 'light')
        # -> None
        
    Example:
        config = {'device': True}
        deep_get(config, 'device', 'settings', 'light')
        # -> TypeError

    Example:
        config = {'device': {'settings': {'light': 'bright'}}}
        deep_get(config, 'device', 'settings', 'light')
        # -> 'light'

    Note that it returns `default` is a key is missing or when it's None.
    It will raise a TypeError if a value is anything else but a dict or None.
    
    Args:
        d: The dict to descend into
        keys: A sequence of keys to follow
        default: Custom default value
    """
    # Descend while we can
    try:
        for k in keys:
            d = d[k]
    # If at any step a key is missing, return default
    except KeyError:
        return default
    # If at any step the value is not a dict...
    except TypeError:
        # ... if it's a None, return default. Assume it would be a dict.
        if d is None:
            return default
        # ... if it's something else, raise
        else:
            raise
    # If the value was found, return it
    else:
        return d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use another library for a solution, this is work best

https://github.com/maztohir/dict-path

```py
from dict-path import DictPath

data_dict = {
  "foo1": "bar1",
  "foo2": "bar2",
  "foo3": {
     "foo4": "bar4",
     "foo5": {
        "foo6": "bar6",
        "foo7": "bar7",
     },
  }
}

data_dict_path = DictPath(data_dict)
data_dict_path.get('key1/key2/key3')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `NestedDict` from the open-source [`ndicts`](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts) package (I am the author), which has a safe `get` method exactly like dictionaries.

```
>>> from ndicts import NestedDict
>>> nd = NestedDict({"key1": {"key2": 0}}
>>> nd.get(("key1", "key2))
0
>>> nd.get("asd")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in external python module, a single function is enough. There is no need to join keys in one string, if argument passing by `*args` is available.

```
def key_chain(data, *args, default=None): 
    for key in args:
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            data = data.get(key, default)
        elif isinstance(data, (list, tuple)) and isinstance(key, int):
            try:
                data = data[key]
            except IndexError:
                return default
        else:
            return default
    return data
```

So just call

```
key_chain(example_dict, "key1", "key2")
```

It doesn't crash with TypeError on the dictonary `example_dict = {'key1': 1}`  unlike [the highest score answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25833661/revisions). It supports integer keys for lists and tuples and default value if any key is missed.

More examples of usage https://gist.github.com/yaznahar/26bd3442467aff5d126d345cca0efcad

Answer (score -2):

You can use [dotted](https://pypi.org/project/dotted/):

`pip install dotted`

```py
from dotted.collection import DottedDict

assert DottedDict(dict(foo=dict(bar="baz")))["foo"]["bar"] == "baz"
assert DottedDict(dict(foo=dict(bar="baz")))["foo.bar"] == "baz"
assert DottedDict(dict(foo=dict(bar="baz"))).get("lorem.ipsum", None) is None
assert DottedDict(dict(foo=dict(bar="baz"))).get("lorem.ipsum", "default") == "default"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this library is abandonware. Last release 7 years ago, and it no longer works with 3.10 after [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#removed) was removed.