# How to programmatically catch which command failed on a try block

Tags: python

I'm trying to get some data from an JSON API. I don't want all the data that the API returns so I wrote a method that reads all the data and returns a dictionary with the relevant fields. Sometimes though, some data are missing and I would like to replace the fields that are missing with an underscore. A sample of the method is like that;

```
return {
    'foo': data['foo'],
    'bar': data['bar']
 }
```

If a field is missing from the data, this throughs a KeyError. Is it possible to catch programmatically which field produced the error, in a single try-except block and not write a try-except block for every field?

```
try:
    ret_dict =  {
        'foo': data['foo'],
        'bar': data['bar']
    }
 except KeyError:
    ret_dict[thefailurekey] = '_'
```

instead of

```
ret_dict = {}
try:
    ret_dict['foo'] = data['foo']
except KeyError:
    ret_dict['foo'] = '_'
try:
    ret_dict['bar'] = data['bar']
except:
    ret_dict['bar'] = '_'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method of [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
def get_data(data):
    return {
        # If you want to accept falsy values from API:
        'foo': data.get('foo', '_'),

        # If you want to override falsy values from API:
        'bar': data.get('bar') or '_',
    }
```

`.get` returns its second argument (`None` by default) if a dict doesn't have requested key, so it is always safe to use it in uncertain situations.

Example:

```
>>> data = {'foo': False, 'bar': False}
>>> get_data(data)
{'bar': '_', 'foo': False}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the field is itself a dictionary, should I use get like that; data.get('foo',{}).get('bar','_') or is there a better-more pythonic way?

Comment: Yes, that's a way to go. Though if you want a more generic method, look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36131992/847552.

Comment: Thank you, that's great. Doesn't get more pythonic than that!

Answer (score 3):

You can probably get that information from the members of the `KeyError` exception object, but a simpler way would be to just use `get()` that will return a default value if the key is not there.

```
return {
    'foo': data.get('foo', '_'),
    'bar': data.get('bar', '_'),
 }
```

Another reason this is better than handling an exception is that you can only handle one exception. What happens if two keys are missing? And on top of that, `ret_dict` will not even be defined in your example because the code failed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Some fields are themselves dictionaries, which means that I need to do something like data['foo']['bar']. Is there a better solution from data.get('foo',{}).get('bar','_')?

Comment: I haven't seen anything better than that.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using try block, you can use `dict.get(key, default_val)`

For example:

```
ret_dict = dict(
    foo=data.get('foo', '-'),
    bar=data.get('bar', '-')
)

return ret_dict
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the field is itself a dictionary, is this good practice; data.get('foo',{}).get('bar','_')?

Comment: yes, that would work but a better approach is to use `defaultdict` for that

Comment: I didn't know about this, I'll check it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the repetitiveness of typing `.get(attr, '_')` for each key, you can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), setting it to return `_` when a key is trying to be accessed but missing.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = {
    'foo': 'foo_value',
}

ret_dict = defaultdict(lambda: '_')
ret_dict.update(data)

print(ret_dict['foo'])  # 'foo_value'
print(ret_dict['bar'])  # '_'
```