# Python get to depth of a dictionary with list

Tags: python

Hello I am parsing a swagger file from an **yaml**.
In order to find the schema I have to parse "#components/schemas/Login"

so in the end I end up with a list -> `['components', 'schemas', 'Login']`

## My question

How can I get to that level using this list?

The point is to get to
`mydict['components']['schemas']['Login']`

of course I can make a function

```
def get_to_dict_lvl_from_an_array(d, arr):
    for i in arr:
        d = d[i]
    return d
```

which does the job, but is this the right and an elegant solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access nested dictionary items via a list of keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys) See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833613/python-safe-method-to-get-value-of-nested-dictionary).

Comment: @hmm yes it does, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the only answer that comes to mind. Since the length is variable, I don't see any good non-iterative way to get to the end. I think it's elegant!

Comment: Yeah, you are right if I pimp it up a little bit with validations it will work. Tnx for your time :)