# How to extract values from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How am I supposed to extract the value `1234` from `"password"`?

```py
account = {
    'Dicky': {
        'password': 1234,
        'balance': {
            'USD': 10,
            'HKD': 10000
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean extract? You could use `account["Dicky"]["password"]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safe method to get value of nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833613/safe-method-to-get-value-of-nested-dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

to extract values form dict:

```
dict["key"]
```

so in your case because there is a nested dict:

```
dict["1stkey"]["2ndkey"]
```

so:

```
account["Dicky"]["password"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, a ***nested dictionary*** is a dictionary inside a dictionary.
example:

```
nested_dict = { 'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'},
            'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'}}
```

so:

```
nested_dict['dict1']['key_A']--->'value_A'
```

this question

```
account = {
'Dicky': {
    'password': 1234,
    'balance': {
        'USD': 10,
        'HKD': 10000
        }
     }
 }

account["Dicky"]["password"]
print(account["Dicky"]["password"])
1234
```