# Pythonic way to use get() default in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, default-value

We know how to use get with a dict in python:

```
a={'k':'thevalue}
a.get('k', 'There is no such key in the dict')
a.get('m', 'There is no such key in the dict')
```

the first one get returns the corresponding value and the second one the default value.

How would you go about the following situation in one liner:

```
a={'k':{'first':'uno','second':'dos'}}
# this is peseudocode:
a.get('k.first', 'There is no such key in the dict')
a.get('k["first"]', 'There is no such key in the dict')
```

meaning if `k` exists in the dict I want the content of the key value first, i.e. `'uno'`.

Comment: `a.get('k', {}).get('first', 'no')`. But that really depends on what keys you do expect and allow to be absent and which not. At some point, `try: a['k']['first'] except KeyError:` becomes easier and more sensible.

Comment: How about chain gets? `a.get('k').get('x', 'whatever')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safe method to get value of nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833613/safe-method-to-get-value-of-nested-dictionary)

Comment: @Karolos `AttributeError: NoneType has no .get`…

Comment: Yap I did not add a default for the first level. You can do as you said in your comment. It was just a sample of chain gets