# How to extract attribute from json in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a json and passed it do a function.
But when I try to extract data it doesn't work.

```
data = {}
data['unit'] = { "id": "052e8reb-d801-89g6-8b26-3bd2da914890" }

test_data(data)

def test_data(data: dict):
    getattr(data.unit, 'id', None)
    getattr(data.get("unit", None), 'id', None)
    data.get('unit').get('id', None)
```

All three methods fail. What should I do to safe get `id` if `unit` is not `None`.
I am new to python.

Comment: The last line should have worked.

Comment: what is data.unit? unit is not attr of data!

Comment: @mkrieger1 but in case that unit is None it doesn't work

Comment: The last line definitely works for the example you provided. If you want to return `None` if the dict has no key `unit`, you could use `data.get('unit',{}).get('id', None)`

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833613/safe-method-to-get-value-of-nested-dictionary.

Comment: @Leonard `('unit',{})` this saved the day. Ty. I was using `None` now I understand why it was failing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's not JSON - that's a dictionary.
So, you can use it like a standard dictionary - `data['unit']['id']` - equivalent to last line (except for if the key is not found), which should work

Comment: I think the question is also about the "safe" part, which I think means that getting the `id` should not throw an error if `unit` or `id` are not set.

Comment: Then the question is confusingly written as: "if `unit` is not `None`" makes me assume that will not happen.

Comment: I agree, it's confusing.