# Python: Safe dictionary access with lists?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, null

Is there an exception free way to access values from a dictionary containing lists. For example, if I have:

```
data = {
    "object_1": {
        "object_2": {
            "list": [
                {
                    "property": "hello"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How do I access the path `data['object_1']['object_2']['list'][0]['property']` safely(i.e. return some default value if not possible to access without throwing error)? I am trying to avoid wrapping these in `try-except`'s. I have seen the [reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46890853/14701745) based approach but it doesn't take into account having lists inside the dictionary.

In JS, I can write something like:

```
data.object_1?.object_2?.list[0]?.property ?? 'nothing_found'
```

Is there something similar in Python?

Comment: You're missing a key there

Comment: Where do you expect None safety to come into play? I can see KeyError and Index error as possibilities here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Actually, that's what I meant - I rephrased the question

Comment: I imagine adding a conditional check for list in the solution you linked would work, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `dict` you can use the `get` method. For lists you can just be careful with the index:

```
data.get('object_1', {}).get('object_2', {}).get('list', [{}])[0].get('property', default)
```

This is a bit awkward because it makes a new temporary dict or lost for each call `get`. It's also not super safe for lists, which don't have an equivalent method.

You can wrap the getter in a small routine to support lists too, but it's not really worth it. You're better off writing a one-off utility function that uses either exception handling or preliminary checking to handle the cases you want to react to:

```
def get(obj, *keys, default=None):
    for key in keys:
        try:
            obj = obj[key]
        except KeyError, IndexError:
            return default
    return obj
```

Exception handing has a couple of huge advantages over doing it the other way. For one thing, you don't have to do separate checks on the key depending on whether the object is a dict or list. For another, you can support almost any other reasonable type that supports `__getitem__` indexing. To show what I mean, here is the asking for permission rather than forgiveness approach:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping, Sequence
from operator import index

def get(obj, *keys, default=None):
    for key in keys:
        if isinstance(obj, Mapping):
            if key not in obj:
                return default
        elif isinstance(obj, Sequence):
            try:
                idx = index(key)
            except TypeError:
                return default
            if len(obj) <= idx or len(obj) < -idx:
                 return default
        obj = obj[key]
    return obj
```

Observe how awkward and error-prone the checking is. Try passing in a custom object instead of a `list`, or a key that's not an integer. In Python, carefully used exceptions are your friend, and there's a reason it's pythonic to ask for forgiveness rather than for permission.

Answer (score 0):

Uggh. Yeah, accessing such JSON data structures is just terrible,
it's a bit awkward.

[Glom](https://pypi.org/project/glom/) to the rescue!

There's two ways to win:

1. You can just specify `... , default=None)` to avoid exceptions, ..or..
2. Use [`Coalesce`](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#defaults-with-coalesce).

   ```
    print(glom(data, {'object_1.object_2.list': ['property']}, default=None))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, x will return None if 'object_1'/'object_2'/'list' key does not exist.

Also, if we are able to access 'list' key then we have x as Not None and we should ensure that the length of the list should be greater than zero and then we can search for 'property' key.

```
x = data.get('object_1', {}).get('object_2', {}).get('list')
    
if x is not None and len(x) > 0:
        print(x[0].get('property'))
else:
        print(None)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Noted @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score -1):

There is one way to do that, but it would involve the `get` method and would involve a lot of checking, or using temporary values.

One example lookup function would look like that:

```py
def lookup(data):
    object_1 = data.get("object_1")
    if object_1 is None:
        # return your default
    object_2 = object_1.get('object_2')
    # and so on...
```

In Python 3.10 and above, there is also structural pattern matching that can help, in which case you would do something like this:

```py
match data:
    case {'object_1': {'object_2': {'list': [{'property': x}]}}}:
        print(x) # should print 'hello'
    case _:
        print(<your_default>)
```

Please remember that this only works with the latest versions of Python (the online Python console on Python.org is still only on Python3.9, and the code above would cause a syntax error).

Comment: Structural pattern matching doesn't use `else`. The syntax for "Other cases" is `case _`. You can learn more about it [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/).

Comment: Thanks, since Python 3.10 is still barely available, I was not able to test it without manually installing 3.10 on my machine (and  it's a pain)