# How to access data in this format: {variable1={key:value,key2:value2.....}, variable2={key3:value3,key4:value4.....}}

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures

I have a dataframe where some columns are formatted this way:

example value of ColX:

```
 {variable1={key:value,key2:value2.....}, variable2={key3:value3,key4:value4.....}}
```

Let's say I want to access value2 and value4. How can I address them using Python?

My desired result is to make a column key2 with value2's and column key4 with all the value4's

Sorry. I could not google the name of this data structure. It's something like a list of dictionary definitions packed into strings.

Comment: what is the datatype of this column?

Comment: @RJ Adriaansen - It's an object

Comment: How about some regex for a quick fix? `df['ColX'].str.findall('(?<=key2:)\w+')`

Comment: You have probably masked the initial keys and values, but were they strings? You'll get a nested dict simply if you remove the outer braces of `CoIX` value , wrap with `dict()` and key-value pairs must be `str`: `n_dict = dict(variable1={'key':'value','key2':'value2'}, variable2={'key3':'value3','key4':'value4'})`. Then you can access anything with chained indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using dictionnaries of dictionnaries (I think). In order to get to value 2 you need to get first to variable 1, and then to key2 so you can do this, if your dictionnary is stored in ColX :

```
ColX.get(variable1).get(key2)
```

By the way are you sure of the syntax of ColX ? Isn't it :

```
{variable1:{key:value,key2:value2.....}, variable2:{key3:value3,key4:value4.....}}
```

Comment: Yes. I am sure about this syntax. This "=" makes all the confusion. But you just brought the idea that I can replace all the "=" with ":" and have nested dictionaries. And this might solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure is simply a nested dict. Try some of the answers given here: [Safe method to get value of nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833613/safe-method-to-get-value-of-nested-dictionary). Dict methods can be concatenated, so you can do:

`dictionary.get(keyname, value).get(keyname, value)`

Comment: Are you sure? I thought nested dictionary looks like this: { 'dictA': {'key_1': 'value_1'},
                'dictB': {'key_2': 'value_2'}} . but here I clearly see "=" sign

Comment: There must be an underlying datastructure as RJ Adriaansen points out. That object is merely a wrapper, so you should investigate what the object uses to build that "dict-like" structure.