# Refactor complex nested ifs into list comprehension

Tags: python

I have rather lengthy nested conditionals that are an eyesore. I've tried to turn it into a list comprehension, but failed. I'm not even sure  if it's feasible to create such list comprehension. My question is how I can turn the script below into a list comprehension, or perhaps I should leave it as is?

Note: The current script works just fine.
The logs coming from the server are really long, so a sample here is not possible.

```
group_name_list = []
for gn in query_res['hits']['hits']:
    if 'user' not in gn['_source']:
        group_name_list.append('-')
    else:
        gn['_source']['user']
        if 'target' not in gn['_source']['user']:
            group_name_list.append('-')
        else:
            gn['_source']['user']['target']
            if 'group' not in gn['_source']['user']['target']:
                group_name_list.append('-')
            else:
                gn['_source']['user']['target']['group']
                if 'name' not in gn['_source']['user']['target']['group']:
                    group_name_list.append('-')
                else:
                    group_name_list.append(gn['_source']['user']['target']['group']['name'])
```

Output:

```
['-', '-', '-', '-', 'Endpoint1', 'PublicWiFi', 'Accounting', 'MobileVPN', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']
```

Comment: The statements in the lines following `else:` like `gn['_source']['user']` are useless, so you can just omit them and then you can merge `else: if:` to `elif:` and get rid of the indentation.

Comment: Actually this can be done with single try/except

Comment: Some of the recipes in the answers here may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833613/safe-method-to-get-value-of-nested-dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that list comprehension would make that better. But the `if`s can be merged into one. That could improve it.:

```py
group_name_list = []
for gn in query_res['hits']['hits']:
    if 'user' in gn['_source']
            and 'target' in gn['_source']['user']
            and 'group' in gn['_source']['user']['target']
            and 'name' in gn['_source']['user']['target']['group']:
        group_name_list.append(gn['_source']['user']['target']['group']['name'])
    else:
        group_name_list.append('-')
```

Or wrap that into try-except:

```py
group_name_list = []
for gn in query_res['hits']['hits']:
    try:
        group_name_list.append(gn['_source']['user']['target']['group']['name'])
    except KeyError:
        group_name_list.append('-')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a list comprehension

```
group_name_list = [gn.get('_source', {}).get('user', {}).get('target', {}).get('group', {}).get('name', '-') for gn in query_res['hits']['hits']]
```

but a `for` loop (using a slight refactoring of [Vojtěch Chvojka' answer catching `KeyError`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76046659/1126841)) is easier to read:

```
group_name_list = []
for gn in query_res['hits']['hits']:
    try:
        name = gn['_source']['user']['target']['group']['name']
    except KeyError:
        name = '-'
    group_name_list.append(name)
```